# cakephp foreach on find and the saveAll

Tags: php, cakephp-2.5

When a user looks at their messages I wish to update each message to READ. I do this by setting the read field to 1/true.

The saveAll does not seems to update the records after my find. I am not sure is the problem with my foreach loop or saveAll, I get no error.

```
array(
'Message' => array(
    'id' => '1',
    'message_text' => 'this isi a test messge',
    'book_id' => '2',
    'page_id' => '1',
    'user_id' => '537765a1-d64c-4529-aa09-5af648257ec7',
    'read' => false,
    'modified' => '2014-05-26 22:36:32',
    'created' => '2014-05-26 22:36:32'
),
'Book' => array(
    'id' => '2',
    'user_id' => '537765',
    'title' => 'test book 2',
    'modified' => '2014-05-18 14:47:30',
    'created' => '2014-05-18 14:47:30'
),
)
```

or if there are many messages

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'Message' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'message_text' => 'this isi a test messge',
        'book_id' => '2',
        'page_id' => '1',
        'user_id' => '537765a1-d64c-4529-aa09-5af648257ec7',
        'read' => false,
        'modified' => '2014-05-26 22:36:32',
        'created' => '2014-05-26 22:36:32'
    ),
    'Book' => array(
        'id' => '2',
        'user_id' => '537765',
        'title' => 'test book 2',
        'modified' => '2014-05-18 14:47:30',
        'created' => '2014-05-18 14:47:30'
    ),
),
(int) 1 => array(
    'Message' => array(
        'id' => '2',
        'message_text' => 'hguhghu uhghuguhg',
        'book_id' => '0',
        'page_id' => '0',
        'user_id' => '537765a1-d64c-4529-aa09-5af648257ec7',
        'read' => false,
        'modified' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
        'created' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
    ),
    'Book' => array(
        'id' => null,
        'user_id' => null,
        'title' => null,
        'modified' => null,
        'created' => null
    ),
)
)
```

My controller code messagesController.php

```
public function index() {
    $this->Message->recursive = 0;
    $conditions = array(
    'conditions' => array('Message.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')),
    );
    $messages = $this->Message->find('all');

    foreach( $messages as $m ):
      $m['Message']['read'] = true;
    endforeach;

    $this->Page->saveAll($messages['Message']);
    $this->set('messages', $messages);
}
```

Another little query on this also is that would this be better suited in the model? Everytime a find is called the model will update the 'read' field.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach( $messages as $m ) {
  $m['Message']['read'] = true;
  $this->Page->saveAll($m);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the replay, the saveAll should be outside the loop as it can save multiple records in one call? I have changed the foreach and it still does not update the record.